# Columns in Context not aligned

Tags: context, columns

I switched from LaTeX to ConTeXt and I am pulling my hair creating a simple column.

When I use a minimal setup like this:

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\starttext
\startcolumns[n=3]
\input knuth
\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

according to the https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Columns, what I get is this output, in which text in columns is not correctly aligned:

[image]

I tried to look through all wikis, handbooks etc, but when this minimalist code sample doesn't show desired results, is there a problem with the installation?

Comment: You would get the same in latex e.g. with multicols if you would force `\fussy` settings.  Small columns have difficulties to align. Find out how to allow more space in the lines (in LaTeX I would e.g. try `\emergencystretch 1em`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ConTeXt provides the two options `stretch` and `extremestretch` for `\setupalign`  (and the `align` key) which use `\emergencystretch`, e.g. `\setupcolumns[align=stretch]` but it is recommended to combine them with other options like `tolerant` (`\setupcolumns[align={tolerant,stretch}]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `align` to `verytolerant` works (as Wolfgang Schuster pointed out in the comments):

```
\setuppapersize[A4]

\starttext

\startcolumns[n=3, align=verytolerant]
\input knuth
\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I used setupcolumns with verytolerant, but that did not affect the output. It's a bit frustrating to learn when even a minimal example does not work as inteded like the wiki or manual :(

Comment: This is very frustrating indeed and obviously a bug. You should report it on the [mailing list](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mailing_Lists)

Comment: @DG' Use the `align` key to set the tolerance, e.g. `\setupcolumns[align=verytolerant]`.

Comment: Thanks, @WolfgangSchuster! Works like a charm